# ArrayList and IEnumerable query

Tags: c#

Why does the following DisplayContents not work(wont compile) for an ArrayList as it inherits form IEnumerable)

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> l = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
            DisplayContents(l);

            string[] l2 = new string[] {"ss", "ee"};
            DisplayContents(l2);

            ArrayList l3 = new ArrayList() { "ss", "ee" };
            DisplayContents < ArrayList>(l3);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void DisplayContents<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            foreach (var _item in collection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry error is "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.ArrayList>'"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ArrayList` implements `IEnumerable`, but not the generic `IEnumerable<T>`. This is to be expected, since `ArrayList` is neither generic nor bound to any specific type.

You need to change the parameter type of your `DisplayContents` method from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable` and remove its type parameter. The items of your collection are passed to `Console.WriteLine`, which can accept any `object`.

```
public static void DisplayContents(IEnumerable collection)
{
    foreach (var _item in collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, don't use `ArrayList` at all since it is unnecessary.  Use `List<object>` if you *really* need to, and the answer to that is probably "no".

Comment: How does it work for an array then? i.e. it works for string[]

Comment: @Noel: arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>` for their specific type.  `ArrayList` is an outdated type, there was no reason to add another interface to it when generics were introduced.

Comment: `string[]` implements `IEnumerable<string>` (as well as `ICollection<string>` and `IList<string>`).

Comment: @EdS.: I agree that an `ArrayList` should be avoided in almost all circumstances.

Comment: @Douglas: Yeah I can't think of any good reason to use one aside from being stuck with an old API that uses it.

Comment: @EdS.: That said, there are plenty of APIs still being released today which don’t properly implement inheritance, especially those interfacing with COM. A popular example is the Outlook Object Model; you may get `MailItem` and `DocumentItem` objects from the same `Folder.Items` collection, whose types have no common ancestor despite sharing most properties. The issue was only alleviated with .NET 4’s `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: If you have to work with those APIs, you might be excused for using `ArrayList`. I’m not aware of the advantages a `List<object>` would have over it.

Comment: @Douglas: The only advantage I see is that it implements `IEnumerable<T>` :)  But yeah, that's what I was saying; you will/should use an ArrayList only when forced to by an API that you do not control.

Comment: You’re right; I’d missed the `IEnumerable<T>` detail. Which is important since `IEnumerable<T>` allows you to leverage LINQ (through the [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) extension methods).

Comment: Is there a good reason that they haven't made ArrayList implement IEnumerable<object>?

Answer (score 4):

Well, a quick check of [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) tells me that `ArrayList` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but instead implements `IEnumerable`, which makes sense as `ArrayList` is a vestigial artifact from the days before generics and has few real uses today.

There's really no reason to use `ArrayList` at all.  You can at least use a `List<object>`, but what problem does that solve?  Unless you absolutely need to have a collection of random types that do not / cannot implement a common interface and cannot be grouped into a new type then use a more specific generic parameter.

Comment: In other words, DON'T USE ARRAYLIST. Use List<T>

Comment: No, seriously. If you are writing code today using ArrayList I WILL SMACK YOU.

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis: Yes, please do. I see it too much on forums.

Comment: I don't use ArrayList, I was just messing about and was wondering why it was not working

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` implements `IEnumerable`, but not generic `IEnumerable<T>`

UPDATE:
This will work:

```
 public static void DisplayContents(IEnumerable collection)
 {
     foreach (var _item in collection)
         Console.WriteLine(_item);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList l3 = new ArrayList() { "ss", "ee" };             
DisplayContents<ArrayList>(l3);
```

Look at your code. You're passing `DisplayContents()` a list of strings but you're telling it to expect a list of ArrayLists.

You probably meant to just call `DisplayContents<string>(l3)`, but as everyone else has already mentioned, that won't work because ArrayList does not implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>`, it only implements `IEnumerable`.

You could instead call

```
DisplayContents<string>((string[])l3.ToArray(typeof(string)));
```

This will work because `string[]` implements `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

How about an extension method?

```
/// <summary>
/// Projects any <see cref="IEnumerable"/>, e.g. an <see cref="ArrayList"/>
/// to an generic <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type to project to.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The source sequence.</param>
/// <param name="map">The mapping function.</param>
/// <returns>A sequence of <typeparamref name="T"/>.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this IEnumerable source, Func<object, T> map)
{
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        yield return map(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you change the calling line to this, it works:

```
    DisplayContents(l3.ToArray());
```

Comment: It works because arrays implement IEnumerable<T>, but that doesn't help the OP understand anything at all.